# This code is used to sort items in a list view by column, but how does it work?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I found the following code on the internet a while ago and am currently using it to sort the items in one of my list views by a specified column. Although I know the code's purpose, I don't know how it actually works, can someone please tell me?

```
Public Class ListViewItemComparer
Implements IComparer
Private column1 As Integer

Public Sub New()
    column1 = 0
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal column2 As Integer)
    column1 = column2
End Sub

Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare

    Dim result As Integer = [String].Compare(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(column1).Text, CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(column1).Text)
    Return result
End Function                                                              
End Class
```

In order to call this code, I am currently doing the following:

```
lstvResults.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer([number of column I want to sort by], SortOrder.Ascending)
```

EDIT: I managed to find where I originally got the code from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=138&v=fRMztyQ06xI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class used by the ListView for item-sorting. It implements the IComparer interface, which has a single method, Comparer.Compare, called internally by the ListView to determine the relative position of one ListViewItem to another.

```
Public Class ListViewItemComparer
Implements IComparer
    Private sortby As SortOrder ' Is this even used?
    Private column1 As Integer  ' Column by which to sort the ListViewItems.

    ' Default constructor: sort by the first column.
    Public Sub New()
        column1 = 0
    End Sub

    ' Parameterized constructor: sort by specified column (with SortOrder?).
    Public Sub New(ByVal column2 As Integer, ByVal sort_by As SortOrder)
        ' Change column sort on to column2.
        column1 = column2 
        sortby = sort_by
    End Sub

    ' Called internally by the ListView to sort its items.
    ' Indicates the position of ListViewItem x relative to ListViewItem y.
    ' Returns 
    '    Less-than-zero if the value of x's Text is less than y's.
    '    Zero if the value of x's Text is equal to y's.
    '    Greater-than-zero if the value of x's text is greater than y's.
    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare

        ' To sort descending, you could flip the positions of x 
        ' and y in the String.Compare call.

        ' Cast x and y each to ListViewItem and compare the values 
        ' of their respective Text properties.
        Dim result As Integer = [String].Compare(CType(x, ListViewItem).SubItems(column1).Text, CType(y, ListViewItem).SubItems(column1).Text)
        Return result
    End Function                                                              
End Class
```

This could be used in a ColumnClick event handler to change the column the ListView is sorted by.

```
' ColumnClick event handler.
Private Sub ColumnClick(ByVal o as object, ByVal e as ColumnClickEventArgs)
    ' Set the ListViewItemSorter property to a new ListViewItemComparer 
    ' object. Setting this property immediately sorts the 
    ' ListView using the ListViewItemComparer object.
    Me.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, SortOrder.Ascending)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this effectively a bubble sort?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's implemented internally, but  it doesn't have to be bubble sort. The C quick sort function qsort() takes a similar function-parameter.

Comment: So this code basically replaces the way the list view would normally sort, that's what the 'lstvResults.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewItemComparer...' line does?

Comment: Yes, that is its purpose. You could use this in a ColumnClick handler to change the  sort-column.

Comment: Glad I could help!